# d3, How to calculate/estimate the delta or position to move grouped nodes on same direction?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to move all nodes of same type in the same direction but without losing their original position in x & y coordinates.

This is the code that listens when a node is dragged:

```
d3.behavior.drag().
    on("drag", function (d) {
        currentDraggedNode = d;
        // now asign the deltas to dx & dy of currentDraggedNode
        currentDraggedNode.dx = d3.event.dx;
        currentDraggedNode.dy = d3.event.dy;
    })
```

After this in my `tick()` method I update position of the nodes but when node has the same type && different _id from `currentDraggedNode` it is not working:

```
nodeElements.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    //if no currentDraggedNode has been selected
    if (currentDraggedNode.type === "") {
        return "translate(" + ( d.x) + "," + ( d.y) + ")";
    }

    //if currentDraggedNode has been selected
    else {    
        if (currentDraggedNode.type === d.type) {
            tempoX = d.x;
            tempoY = d.y;
            if (currentDraggedNode._id === d._id) {
                return "translate(" + (tempoX ) + "," + (tempoY) + ")";
            } else {
// ============ THIS IS THE CASE THAT DOES NOT WORK!!!!!!!!!!!! ===========
                tempoX +=currentDraggedNode.dx;
                tempoY +=currentDraggedNode.dy;
                return "translate(" + (tempoX) + "," + (tempoY) + ")";
            }
        } else {
            return "translate(" + ( d.x) + "," + ( d.y) + ")";
        }
    }
});
```